# Camel read properties file

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

How do I configure the use of a properties file using Java DSL and the Main object?

According to [this page](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html) I should be able to call something like:

```
main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations("example.properties");
```

However that simply doesn't work.  It seems that option wasn't added until Camel 2.18 and I'm running 2.17.1.

**What was the original way to set a properties file to use when letting the application run in a standalone form?**

Some backstory:

I'm trying to convert from Spring to Java DSL.  During that conversion I was attempting to have my Camel application run on its own.  I know that is achieved using `main.run();`.

I had things "functioning" when using the CamelContext, but that cannot run on its own.  So I know using the following will work in that case:

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:/myProperties.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

Is there some way I can tell the `main` to use that setup?  Or is there something else needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:/myProperties.properties");
main.getCamelContexts().get(0).addComponent("properties", pc);
```

Also, if you are using `camel-spring`, you could use [`org.apache.camel.spring.Main`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/Main.java) class, it should use the property placeholder from your application context.

Comment: Ahh short, sweet and to the point.  Thanks!  You'd think it would be a little cleaner than that.  But I suppose that's why they introduced the new method in Camel 2.18!

Comment: If you're moving to Java config you should also give Spring Boot a try - [Camel has great support for it](https://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html), removes a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mentioning you are in the process to move from Spring XML to Java Config here's a minimum application that is using properties and injecting it into a Camel route (it's really properties management in Spring injected into our Camel route bean):

**my.properties**:

```
something=hey!
```

**Main class**:

package camelspringjavaconfig;

```
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.Main;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("camelspringjavaconfig")
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
public class MyApplication extends CamelConfiguration {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setConfigClass(MyApplication.class);  // <-- passing to the Camel Main the class serving as our @Configuration context
        main.run();   // <-- never teminates
    }
}
```

**MyRoute class**:

```
package camelspringjavaconfig;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;   //<-- we are wiring the Spring Env

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(env.getProperty("something"));  //<-- so that we can extract our property

        from("file://target/inbox")
                .to("file://target/outbox");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's neat, didn't realize you could configure things using the annotations! I wish the Camel pages had a little bit of a cleaner flow so I could find some of these things out